# Maven plugin to delete jar file when building war

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a jar (withnative.jar) that loads a Native Interface load code. The said jar has dependency to a webapp. But because I want to isolate the loader used by the Native Interface loading jar, I will place the withnative.jar in the lib directory of tomcat and not embed it with my war file.

However, I have referenced some of the class in the withnative.jar in my webapp. Hence, outright removing the withnative.jar in my pom.xml will generate eclipse error on my IDE.

How can I remove the withnative.jar only during the building of my war file. So it will not be embedded in my webapps? Maybe a maven plugin is already existing?

Comment: Why dont you just use maven with a scope: `runtime` in your pom.xml ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark that dependency as provided:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>blabla</groupId>
  <artifactId>withnative</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Maven will add it to the compilation classpath, but will not package it.